# Whitespaces in Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

I am trying to "parse" command line-arguments for when I start my program from a file in Explorer.

The problems seems to be that the `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` method cuts arguments at whitespaces. 
This means I cannot open files witch contains whitespaces in its filename.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add quotes around files with whitespace "C:\Some Directory\SomeFile.txt"

Comment: I feel so silly.. Since I was adding my own arguments from the projects properties I didn't add the quotation marks around them.. Well, thank you!